# ggplot2 group overrides fill command

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am kinda new to R and learning ggplot and faced a code to fix

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = after_stat(prop),group=1))
```

I need it to show color with the grouping but it seems the group command overrides the fill one.

How should I deal with this? And please refer to a source if possible I would like to learn more about it

Comment: I think this might help you: https://www.gl-li.com/2017/08/13/ggplot2-group-overrides-default-grouping/

Comment: That is really awesome, @ViníciusFélix

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to calculate the data you want to plot before to better understand what happened with ggplot2 stats (here `after_stat`)

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d2 <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))
```

Then prop is calculated you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(data = d2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = prop))
```

You can then add labels with geom_text:

```
ggplot(data = d2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = prop)) + 
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = cut, group = color, y = prop, 
                          label = scales::percent(prop, accuracy = 1)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

To have props calculated globally, ungroup:

```
library(tidyverse)
d2 <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

ggplot(data = d2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = prop))
```

Comment: This is not actually the plot intended as the result of this plot is columns all equal 1 of same height but we wanted them to show actual difference between them but in prop

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: I edited my answer with a second ggplot2 code. I'm not sure I really understand what you want to achieve but I think the idea is behind not too far